# Combine List and Dictionary in 1 Dictionary

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

**Dictionary:**

```
Dictionary<int, int> ProductIdQuantityDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Filled with:

```
1, 54
2, 78
3,  5
6, 13
```

(Filled with ProductId at *key* and Quantity at *value*.)

I have a `list<int>` as well.

**List:**

```
List<int> CategoryIdList = new List<int>();
```

Filled with:

```
1
5
6
7
```

(Filled with CategoryId.)

Psuedo code it should be something like:

```
Dictionary<CategoryIdList, ProductIdQuantityDictionary> MergedDictionary = new Dictionary<CategoryIdList, ProductIdQuantityDictionary>();
```

The result should look like:

```
1, 1, 54
5, 2, 78
6, 3, 5
7, 6, 13
```

I heard something about `Tuple`, but I don't have a clue how to implement. Is there an easy way for filling a dictionary with more than 2 values, if this is even possible?

Note: The most important part of the question: How can I combine a `Dictionary` and `List` in a new `Dictinary`.

Comment: What links, for example, category5 to product2

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain, flagged as Off topic?

Comment: I don't know if I understood you: you have products that belong to categories?

Comment: First in List needs to link to First in dictionary

Comment: fyi the order in a dictionary is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Arie Yes indeed, products are linked to categories.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Are you just zipping everything together?

Comment: Yes for simplifying my question, in the source I'm not zipping together, the redline of the question is getting a list and dictionary combined in a new dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Zip` method:

```
var merged = ProductIdQuantityDictionary.Zip(CategoryIdList, (pair, id) => 
                 new 
                 { 
                     CategoryId = id,
                     ProductId = pair.Key,
                     Quantity = pair.Value
                 })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.CategoryId );
```

The `Dictionary<int,int>` gives an indeterminate order. Lacking the explanation of how `Category` and `Product` relate from your question, this is the closest I can suggest.

**Update**

Your question and pseudo-code are unclear. I don't think you want

```
Dictionary<List<int>, Dictionary<int,int>>
```

I think you are looking for something closer to

```
Dictionary<int, <int, int>>
```

where `<int, int>` is some object containing the `ProductId` and `Quantity`.

The above answer gives you

```
Dictionary<int, <int, int, int>>
```

where

```
<int, int, int>
```

is an anonymous object with the structure:

```
{
    int CategoryId { get; set; }
    int ProductId  { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to order items before ziping or lookup in dictionary while selectiong ids... Method as you proposed can cause bugs when items are out of order.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes, as noted in the answer. There is not enough detail in the question to determine order.

Comment: Added note, explaining most important part of question.

Answer (score 2):

can't you do

```
//Dictionary<catId, Dictionary<prodId, quantity>>
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary can have a collection as a value, including another dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>>
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>
```

Alternatively, Tuple is a small, model of a class essentially - where all you have are some properties.  Downside is how you access them - not named so can be confusing.

```
Tuple<int, int, int> myTuple = new Tuple<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3);
DoWork(myTuple.Item1, myTuple.Item2, myTuple.Item3);
```

If you go Tuple route, you can use it in a collection (including dictionary)

```
List<Tuple<int, int, int>> myTuples = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
foreach(var myTuple in myTuples)
    DoWork(myTuple.Item1, myTuple.Item2, myTuple.Item3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might look appealing, concise and clear. You can link as many attributes to your product as required. But then, maybe, you could consider making it a class `Product` with all attributes as properties.

```
struct ProductAttributes
{
    public int Quantity;
    public List<int>Categories;
}

Dictionary<int ProductId, ProductAttributes> = new Dictionary<Int, ProductAttributes>();
```

Or you can go crazy by doing something like (pseudo code): `Dict<Dict<Dict<KeyValuePair<List<Dict<T, T>>, T>>>> = new Dict<Dict<Dict<KeyValuePair<List<Dict<T, T>>, T>>>>();` and nest all your product attributes in a one-liner if you like :D But if you like one-liners, Tuples may be what you seek: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var combined = new List<Tuple<int,int.int>>()
for(int i=0; i<categoryList.Count(); i++)
{
 var e = categoryList[i];
 var dicKeys = ProductIdQuantityDictionary.Keys;
 if(i < dicKeys.Count()){
 combined.Add(new Tuple(e,dicKeys[i],ProductIdQuantityDictionary[dicKeys[i]]))
 }
 else
 {
  combined.Add(new Tuple(e,0,0))
 }
}
```

Later you can just access it as

```
 foreach(var t in Combined)
  {
    //t.Item1;
    //t.Item2;
    //t.Item3;
  }
```